# Dar opacidad a un card pero inputs y buttons sin opacidad

Tags: css3, bootstrap-4

[image: imagen de diseño]Estoy dando diseño a un formulario de login que está en un card (bootstrap4). El card debe tener una opacidad blanca y los labels, inputs son blancos pero sin opacidad (lo que hace que resalten).  El problema es que una vez que se pone la opacidad se hereda a los labels e inputs. ¿Alguna ayuda para hacer que el contenido no tenga opacidad?

```
  .card{
            
            background-color: white;
             opacity: 0.1;   
        }
        .card label{
       
            color: white;
           
        }
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Debes compartir un poco más de código de manera que nos permita reproducir el problema. Así es más fácil ayudarte. Te extiendo una invitación a hacer el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que ganes reputación y conozcas las reglas.

Answer (score 0):

Podés colocar el estilo directamente en la etiqueta del elemento (en tu caso en el input). Le subís la opacidad dentro de html y eso supera a bootstrap

Comment: Probablemente estés haciendo referencia a [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Para redactar una respuesta más elaborada, lee [answer].

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, Estoy aprendiendo mucho, la próxima vez trataré de seguir  las pautas sobre Cómo responder.